# Jedis pool stops working when another instance uses PubSubs

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm currently creating 2 java programs which should (but must not) work side by side.
For simplicity call them S1 and S2.

S1 is a simple API that pulls or pushes data from/to redis. For this I initialize a JedisPool on startup and later use this pool to interact with redis.

S2 is a system that communicates in realtime with a master using PubSub.

Creating the pool:

```
private JedisPool jedisPool;
public void startup(){
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(128);
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "127.0.0.1", 6379, 10000);
}
```

And using it later

```
    public void set(String key, String value) {
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        jedis = Main.getInstance().getJedisPool().getResource();
        jedis.clientSetname(key);
        jedis.set(key, value);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jedis.close();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Creating the pubSub for system 2:

```
public static void runPubSub() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        Jedis jedis = null;
        try {
            jedis = new Jedis();
            JedisPubSub jedisPubSub = new JedisPubSub() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
                    if (channel.equals(Main.getInstance().getTypeManager().getName())) {
                        //handle Command
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
                    System.out.println("Client is Subscribed to channel : " + channel);
                    System.out.println("Client is Subscribed to " + subscribedChannels + " channels");
                }

                @Override
                public void onUnsubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
                    System.out.println("Client is Unsubscribed from channel : " + channel);
                    System.out.println("Client is Subscribed to " + subscribedChannels + " channels");
                }

            };
            jedis.subscribe(jedisPubSub, Main.getInstance().getTypeManager().getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (jedis != null)
                jedis.close();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Now to the specific problem:
As soon as I start both, S1 and S2, then S1 stops working. S2 works fine.
When using only S1 everything works fine.

Can anyone help me out here?